# How was the gui for Visual Studio 2012 achieved and how can we make similar looking applications

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 2012, being run under desktop mode under windows 8. Doesn't share the look of other windows 8 desktop applications.

How was this GUI achieved?

Did Microsoft scrap MFC/Winapi altogether (since its so different) and use Direct2d to create the custom gui? Or, have they just made calls to Winapi to customize it they way it looks?

Is there any shortcut for us developers to implement the vs2012 theme in our applications? Using the MFC Application template wizard we can chose from many themes but no vs2012 alike is available.

Comment: It's just a WPF theme...  You can build your own or grab one from http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take Spy++ which comes with Visual Studio and inspect the windows/class names of the application.  If you do it with VS 2008, it's obvious that it's MFC.  If you do it with VS 2010 and later, you will see that it's all WPF stuff--no MFC involved.

Comment: Do you know of anyway to easily match the theme using mfc/win32 or just c++ in general?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, Visual Studio 2010/2012 leverages WPF.

LEVERAGING WPF

WPF utilizes DirectX. WPF attempts to provide a consistent programming model for building applications and provides a separation between the user interface and the business logic. WPF leverages XAML, which is a declarative markup language.  XAML stands for eXtensible Application Markup Language, which is based on XML.  XAML is designed as a more efficient method of developing application user interfaces

ITS ABOUT MULTIPLE DOCUMENT WINDOWS AND FLOATING TOOL WINDOWS

Visual Studio was written to support multiple document windows and floating tool windows.

GREAT LIBRARIES ARE AVAILABLE

Codeplex provides a library to model the multiple document windows.
http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

There is also a docking library you can leverage:
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

MEF IS USED HEAVILY

The internals have been redesigned using Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF).

MEF allows application developers to discover and use extensions without messing around with configuration files.

MEF allows you to easily encapsulate code and avoid fragile hard dependencies.

This allows developers to create add-ins to modify the behavior of the IDE.

DESIGN GOALS

In Visual Studio 2012, a one change is that the interface uses of all-caps menu bar.

Some design goals include reduced clutter and visual complexity by removing excessive lines and gradients in the UX.

The UI has been modernized by removing outdated 3D bevels.